# How to display the values in open faces datatable?

Tags: jsf, openfaces

Actually i am using open faces data table for selecting rows using the attribute < o:checkboxColumn rowDatas will automatically filter the currently selected rows .I didn't do any filter in Bean file,the selected list values are stored in my database table .My problem is how to display the selected list to other data table , if i did iteration  only the values will be display (there is no need of iteration here ).

```
<o:dataTable id="type_parts_table"
                            value="#{employeeBean.srNameList}" 
                            applyDefaultStyle="true" var="type_parts" width="600px"
                            pageSize="10" headerRowClass="header-table-row"
                            bodyRowClass="normal-table-row"
                            bodySectionClass="normal-table-row"
                            sortedColumnHeaderClass="sorted-header-row">
                            <o:column width="200px">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Name" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{type_parts.name}" />
                            </o:column>


                            <o:column width="200px">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Type" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{type_parts.head}" />
                            </o:column></o:dataTable>
```

Is there any attribute to display those values .

Comment: Can you please your bean code? Regards,

Comment: I got answer myself ,thanks for all the people who viewed my questions

Comment: Can you please share your solution? That will be great!